# Bundling OpenJDK with install4j installer

Tags: java, install4j

The release notes of install4j mention

> Release 7.0.5  2018-05-10 New features:
>
> ```
> • Support OpenJDK installations when creating JRE bundles
> ```

In the JRE bundle download wizard, I am missing the information whether the downloaded JREs will be Oracle JDK or OpenJDK.

How can I specifically bundle my app with an OpenJDK JRE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to Java 10, the downloaded JRE bundles are Oracle JREs, from Java 11 onwards, they are OpenJDK JREs.